# How to edit greyed key bindings set in Xcode 11

Tags: xcode, xcode11

I want to change the key binding set in Xcode 11 some are editable bur some are greyed which I cannot edit, how to unlock it.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can change them! Here's what you do:

1. Open the file `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/KeyBindings/Default.idekeybindings`
2. Look for the the name of the binding you want to change.
3. Change the value inside of the `<string>` tag underneath the `<key>` with value `<Alternate>` from **YES** to **NO**
4. Close and open Xcode
5. Navigate to keybindings, then change your newly, not-greyed-out binding to whatever you want!

Answer (score 1):

Because they are similar to other editable shortcuts thus are treated as something like dependent variables.

In the **File Menu** section for example, the `Close Tab` (CMD+W) shortcut is editable. Meanwhile, the similar shortcuts (`Close Other Tabs` (Option+CMD+W), `Close Window` (Shift+CMD+W), `Close Other Windows` (Control+Option+CMD+W), `Close All Windows` (Option+Shift+CMD+W)) are not editable (greyed).

But when I change `Close Tab` from (CMD+W) to (CMD+M), the **W** in the keys of all those similar shortcuts will be changed accordingly to **M**.

You can verify this on your computer.

Comment: ok I am still in confusion. let me tell you a specific shortcut to change *Open library* form (Option + Shift + Command + L) to (Command + Shit + A)

Comment: @MeetIosDeveloper maybe I didn't explain well. I made some updates.

Comment: Let me tell you a specific shortcut to change *Open library* form (Option + Shift + Command + L) to (Command + Shit + A)

Comment: In this case `Option` is not optional.

Answer (score 1):

To be clear, you cannot edit key bindings that are grayed out. They are generated based on the preceding setting. For example, if the preceding settings is `⌘2` then the grayed out setting below may add `⌥` to become `⌘⌥2`.

If you're astonished at how poor this design is, then rest assured that your understanding is correct.

As a workaround, I use BetterTouchTool to remap my shortcuts. For example to "close other tabs" I remap `⌘⇧W` (my preferred shortcut) to `⌥⌘W` (Xcode's default) and have it only apply to the Xcode app.